# Providing Centroids and Then Clustering

Tags: cluster-analysis, centroid

I seem to find a lot of documentation based on computing centroids and clustering, but what if I assign centroid values themselves.

Say if I provide 14 different centroid vectors. How would I go about clustering my data to those 14 different centroid values?

Maybe this is an easy question, but I haven't found an answer online, so wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the centroids are predefined, then you are doing **nearest-neighbor classification**, not clustering. It's only clustering if the structure is *not* predefined.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure this belongs in the python forum, but you just need to compute the distance from each of your points to each centroid, and then assign each point to that centroid that is closest. You then have your clusters, though some may be empty (no guarantee that a centroid will have at least one data point closest to it). You can do this by iterating over all of your points, or do it much more quickly in one step using matrices with numpy. I've got some code lying around somewhere if you need an example to get started.

Comment: Okay I figured it must be something like that. Thanks!